# GMAPS API event handling for pin points

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an api for gmaps and i have some markers for it, when a specific marker gets clicked i want it to update some html outside of the api, now i could do this no problem if it was just a regular thing but the way the script is it is object oriented, there's no way i can inspect the markers and say when x is clicked update innerhtml of y to etc...

```
     var map;
/*array for locations below */
var locations = [
  ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment Liverpool <br/><br/> 11th Floor, The Plaza<br/> 100 Old Hall Street <br/> Liverpool <br/> L3 9QJ <br/> <br/> 0151 242 1630</h4>', 53.4109146,-2.9947334999999384],

  ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment Manchester <br/><br/> Centurion House<br/>129 Deansgate<br/>Manchester<br/>M3 3WR <br/> <br/> 0161 393 9889  </h4>', 53.479798 , -2.2479048],

  ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment London <br><br> Warnford Court <br> 29 Throgmorton Street<br> London <br>  EC2N 2AT <br><br> 0203 817 7030</h4>', 51.5074, 0.1278],
  ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment Birmingham <br><br> Cornwall Buildings <br> 45 Newhall Street <br> Birmingham <br> B3 3QR <br><br> 0121 796 8460</h4>', 52.48208, -1.9027578],


  ['<h4>Kingsley Recruitment Leeds <br><br> West One <br> Wellington Street<br>Leeds<br>LS1 1BA <br><br>0113 887 2170 </h4>', 53.8008 , -1.5491]
];

// Setup the different icons and shadows
var iconURLPrefix = 'https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/';

var icons = [
  iconURLPrefix + 'marker_black.png',

]

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
var center = map.getCenter();
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
map.setCenter(center); 
});

var iconsLength = icons.length;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('MAPS'), {
  zoom: 6,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.6369, -1.1398),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  streetViewControl: true,
  scrollwheel:false,
  panControl: false,
  zoomControlOptions: {
     position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
  }
});





var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  maxWidth: 160
});

var markers = new Array();

var iconCounter = 0;

// Add the markers and infowindows to the map
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2],locations[i][3],locations[i][4]),
    map: map,
    icon: icons[iconCounter]
  });

  markers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

  iconCounter++;

  if(iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
    iconCounter = 0;
  }
}

function autoCenter() {
  //  Create a new viewpoint bound
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  //  Go through each...
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
    bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
  }
  //  Fit these bounds to the map
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
autoCenter();
```

i want it to update the li inner html below

```
    <div class = "contact-icons">
      <ul>
      <div class = "indiv-icons">
       <img src = "images/call-icon.PNG"/> <li>CALL US <br/> +333 333 333 </li>
      </div>
      <div class = "indiv-icons"> 
       <img src = "images/address-icon.PNG"/> <li>ADDRESS<br/> 1234 Quigley Street</li>
      </div>
      <div class = "indiv-icons">  
       <img src = "images/message-icon.PNG"/> <li>EMAIL<br/> support@yourcompany.com</li>
      </div> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

To me this seems like a complex task which is why i am putting it on here the website it's self so you can see it is, http://79.170.40.182/kingsley-test.co.uk/kingsley%209.9.2016/kingsley-new/contact.php

Answer (score 0):

what function do you want it to call when you click on a marker? Is it only one marker you want to add the event to or all the markers?

If it is all the markers, just add

```
nameOfYourFunction(marker)
```

just after where it says

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
```